How to make form responses post to the website?
I am trying to make a website that users can fill out a form on one page, and have those answers post automatically to another page on the site. Is there a way to do this?
I have an HTML/CSS site right now and the form is created, right now the responses just come to my email.

Make sure your form is pointing to the PHP file that will process it.
// your form
<form action="submit_form.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
// form submission
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

$file = 'responses.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "$name: $message\n", FILE_APPEND);

header('Location: display.php');
exit();
?>

// your display page
<?php
$file = 'responses.txt';
$responses = file_get_contents($file);
echo nl2br($responses);
?>

In the real world you would use a Database to stock your files but here it's just for the example.
